# Plaid remove transaction webhook

Tags: plaid

If I remove the transactions webhook will that prevent plaid from requesting transactions from the bank?

Im looking to decrease the number of times a user needs to update Oauth yet still have an accurate live account balance.

Im hoping I can remove the transactions product and webhook and just query balance at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

A user in general shouldn’t need to update OAuth regularly to use Transactions.

It is not possible to remove Transactions from an Item. Removing the webhook endpoint from the Item will prevent webhooks from being sent but will not have any other impact on the Item.